# Proper way of installing puttygen on Amazon Linux

Tags: putty, puttygen, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install `puttygen` on an Amazon Linux server. `puttygen` is provided by the `putty` package available in EPEL, but installation fails with it unable to find several required C libraries:

```
Error: Package: putty-0.63-7.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: putty-0.63-7.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: putty-0.63-7.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: putty-0.63-7.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
```

Currently I'm installing putty on a Centos 6 box, then copying the binary `/usr/bin/puttygen` on to the Amazon Linux box. This works for my use-case, but I'm not keen on circumventing the package manager in this way. Is there a 'proper' way of doing things?

Comment: Looks like you need to use yum install libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 on the AWS Linux box and then install puttygen

Comment: @ryekayo trying that command gives me "No package libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 available.". What repository are you able to access it in?

Comment: This question has the same goal as the named duplicate, but this OP cannot run puttygen because they cannot install putty.